# createMuiTheme overrides, for a particular component style

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to override the default style of a particular Material UI component style? Let's say I want have different types of [`MuiButton`](https://material-ui.com/api/button/)'s...

```
<Button color="primary" variant="contained">Foo</Button>
<Button variant="text">Foo</Button>
```

With the default styles the first button will have a white text color and the second one will have a black text color. If I would like to change the text color default globally (which in this case I won't) I should use the following options for [`createMuiTheme`](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#createmuitheme-options-theme):

```
const options = {
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
          color: 'white',
      }
    }
  }
};
```

However in this case I would only like to change the text color of the primary colored and contained variant button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override) it was not very clear to me but apparently you can target different classes in the component like so:

```
const options = {
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      containedPrimary: {
        '& > .MuiButton-label': {
          color: 'white'
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```